# how to remove an item from a UnmodifiableList in a protobuf

Tags: java, list, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a protobuf with a list as one of its members

I want to replace an item in this list.

I tried to remove an item `i` and add another one at same position `i`

```
List<Venues.Category> categoryList = builder.getCategoryList();

    categoryList.remove(i);
```

but I get an unsupported error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.remove(Collections.java:1317)
```

How can I perform the replacement?

Comment: Is your categoryList is converted from array?

Comment: List<Venues.Category> categoryList = builder.getCategoryList();

Comment: I'd like to know inside the **builder.getCategoryList()** is worked by array or list?

Comment: @EladBenda check my answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up cloning the list, modifying the cloned list and putting it instead of the old one.

```
List<Venues.Category> clone = categoryList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                clone.remove(i);
                clone.add(i, modifyCategory(category, countryAbbr, gasStationConfig));

                builder.clearCategory();
                builder.addAllCategory(clone);
```

Comment: This is limited to one class is there any possibility that we can create all sub class also mutable. so that we can update any inner class object upto any level of inner class?

Answer (score 5):

One of the solution is to create a new modifiable list which wraps the old one - I mean passing it to the constructor of e.g. new `ArrayList()`:

```
List<T> modifiable = new ArrayList<T>(unmodifiable);
```

Since now, you should be able to remove and add the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If your List come from array, it will throw **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**.

```
/*Example*/
String[] strArray = {"a","b","c","d"};

List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArray);

strList.remove(0); // throw exception
```

Because the original array and the list are **linked.**

The size of the list is *fixed size* and changes will effect on both.

**add()** or **remove()** can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update protobuff builder list, you can achieve with this :

```
      //Considering builder is your Category list builder.
    List<Venues.Category> categoryList = builder.getCategoryList(); // Previous list.

        builder.setCategory(1, categoryBuilder.build()); //categoryBuilder is your object builder which you want to replace at first location.
// Hope you will get setCategory function by protobuffer, or something like that. because it's created by protobuffer compilation.

        List<Venues.Category> updatedCategoryList = builder.getCategoryList();
    //Your updated list with new object replaced at 1.
```